UX concerns with showing dynamic tips/fun facts/"Did you know...?" section on a loading progress modal
In my app, there's a window that opens up with a spinning logo next to a progress bar that shows update/loading progress. I want to add a section with various tips and fun facts about the application, but I'm concerned that this will cause UX issues. Are there any UX issues with adding this feature, and if so, how will I be able to address them?

This would expose a few minor UX issues. All could be solved, and even if they aren't I doubt they'd be blockers to actually implementing this.

Useful Tips/Info Reading Time: If you're showing helpful tips, valuable information could get cut-off during read on a fast progress. Can users access these tips elsewhere? For fun facts that's probably not required but any useful information should fall under Usability Heuristic #3: User Control & Freedom, users should have the ability to find useful information when they want it.
What are users waiting for?: This could cause frustration depending on what your users are actually doing. If they're waiting for a 3D model to render or something, totally fine. If they're submitting immigration paperwork or something more stressful or emotionally involved you should be very sensitive to tone.
Would your user prioritize this over other features?: If you have regular users on your app that are making functional feature requests or waiting for updates, seeing a semi-fluffy new feature like this could result in some users feeling their needs are being ignored. This depends a lot on what you app and user base actually are.


Showing tips and fun facts can be good UX - distraction makes loading times seem shorter, users like learning things in a way that doesn't interrupt their tasks, and it can make the loading experience more useful, overall.
Some best practices:

Keep the messages short enough to read in the allocated loading time, you don't them to disappear before loading is done.
Make messages valuable, this is not the place for marketing fluff or upselling.
If there is existing content on the screen, try not to cover it with the message.
Be aware of tone. The user is waiting on the system, wait times cause stress. Be respectful and calming.

